# How to understand masked multi-head attention in transformer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, transformer-model, attention-model

I'm currently studying code of transformer, but I can not understand the masked multi-head of decoder. The paper said that it is to prevent you from seeing the generating word, but I can not unserstand if the words after generating word have not been generated, how can them be seen?

I try to read the code of transformer (link:https://github.com/Kyubyong/transformer). The code achieved mask is shown below. It uses the lower triangular matrix to mask, I can not understand why.

```py
padding_num = -2 ** 32 + 1
diag_vals = tf.ones_like(inputs[0, :, :])  # (T_q, T_k)
tril = tf.linalg.LinearOperatorLowerTriangular(diag_vals).to_dense()  # (T_q, T_k)
masks = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tril, 0), [tf.shape(inputs)[0], 1, 1])  # (N, T_q, T_k)
paddings = tf.ones_like(masks) * padding_num
outputs = tf.where(tf.equal(masks, 0), paddings, inputs)
```

Answer (score 65):

I had the very same question after reading the [Transformer paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762). I found no complete and detailed answer to the question in the Internet so I'll try to explain my understanding of Masked Multi-Head Attention.

The short answer is - we need masking to make the training parallel. And the parallelization is good as it allows the model to train faster.

Here's an example explaining the idea. Let's say we train to translate "I love you" to German. The encoder works in parallel mode - it can produce vector representation of the input sequence ("I love you") within a constant number of steps (i.e. the number of steps doesn't depend on the length of the input sequence).

Let's say the encoder produces the numbers `11, 12, 13` as the vector representations of the input sequence. In reality these vectors will be much longer but for simplicity we use the short ones. Also for simplicity we ignore the service tokens, like  - beginning of the sequence,  - end of the sequence and others.

During the training we know that the translation should be "Ich liebe dich" (we always know the expected output during the training). Let's say the expected vector representations of the "Ich liebe dich" words are `21, 22, 23`.

If we make the decoder training in sequential mode, it'll look like the training of the Recurrent Neural Network. The following sequential steps will be performed:

- Sequential operation #1. Input: `11, 12, 13`.

  - Trying to predict `21`.
  - The predicted output won't be exactly `21`, let's say it'll be `21.1`.
- Sequential operation #2. Input: `11, 12, 13`, and also `21.1` as the previous output.

  - Trying to predict `22`.
  - The predicted output won't be exactly `22`, let's say it'll be `22.3`.
- Sequential operation #3. Input `11, 12, 13`, and also `22.3` as the previous output.

  - Trying to predict `23`.
  - The predicted output won't be exactly `23`, let's say it'll be `23.5`.

This means we'll need to make 3 sequential operations (in general case - a sequential operation per each input). Also we'll have an accumulating error on each next iteration. Also we don't use attention as we only look to a single previous output.

As we actually know the expected outputs we can adjust the process and make it parallel. There's no need to wait for the previous step output.

- Parallel operation #A. Inputs: `11, 12, 13`.

  - Trying to predict `21`.
- Parallel operation #B. Inputs: `11, 12, 13`, and also `21`.

  - Trying to predict `22`.
- Parallel operation #C. Inputs: `11, 12, 13`, and also `21, 22`.

  - Trying to predict `23`.

This algorithm can be executed in parallel and also it doesn't accumulate the error. And this algorithm uses attention (i.e. looks to all previous inputs) thus has more information about the context to consider while making the prediction.

And here is where we need the masking. The training algorithm knows the entire expected output (`21, 22, 23`). It hides (masks) a part of this known output sequence for each of the parallel operations.

- When it executes #A - it hides (masks) the entire output.
- When it executes #B - it hides 2nd and 3rd outputs.
- When it executes #C - it hides 3rd output.

Masking itself is implemented as the following (from the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)):

> We implement this inside of scaled dot-product attention by masking
>   out (setting to −∞) all values in the input of the softmax which
>   correspond to illegal connections

Note: during the inference (not training) the decoder works in the sequential (not parallel) mode as it doesn't know the output sequence initially. But it's different from RNN approach as Transformer inference still uses self-attention and looks at all previous outputs (but not only the very previous one).

Note 2: I've seen in some materials that masking can be used differently for non-translation applications. For example, for language modeling the masking can be used to hide some words from the input sentence and the model will try to predict them during the training using other, non-masked words (i.e. learn to understand the context).

Comment: I recommend this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-guide-to-transformers-step-by-step-explanation-f74876522bc0), with your explanation and the article it helps a lot.

Comment: +1 for the really helpful example. With this, I am clear on src_mark. Still, src_key_padding_mask is a bit fuzzy to me. Is the to ignore few padding tokens at the end of a single sequence?

Comment: Helped me a lot thanksssss

Comment: I understand what you explained. but if decoder is taking the target sequence, then how the decode auto-regressive? I think definition of auto-regression is using the past predictions to predict the future.

Comment: hi, is mask needed for decoder in inference mode?

Comment: The article linked in the first response is a blatant (and worse) copy of [this article](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer). I highly recommend reading the original article instead.

Comment: Nice answer! Also wanted to add that the process mentioned by you during training is known as "teacher forcing" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teacher_forcing ) and it was initially done in RNN context in order to avoid error propagation (just as you mentioned it).

Answer (score 1):

decoder is a self-regressor and can't see the future words

1. encoder in transformer is a self-regressor;
2. which means it will predict the next token according to the previous;
3. so input `x` can't see the future words;
4. we use masked multi-head attention to do this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31696745)

Comment: I think it is a simple question and give a short answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the text we're training on is
"one two three four five"

This is self-supervised training and we're just going to train the model to predict the next word in the sequence. Rather than an encoder-decoder model we'll just use a GPT-style transformer (sometimes called "decoder only" because it's "causal," sometimes called "encoder only" because no cross-attention).

If we're doing generative pre-training we're going to train this model with:
`input_tokens = [one, two, three, four]`
and
`output_tokens [ two, three, four, five ]`
We shift the tokens such that the model is always predicting the next token.

Now, for the output "two," we only want to consider the input "one". When learning to generate the output "three" we only want to consider the inputs "one" and "two." And so on.

Now, after pre-training, we'll feed into the model "Mary had a little" and we expect to get the output "had a little lamb." The output is shifted by one token.

It may seem wasteful to train on the entire sentence in the output. You may be asking yourself, why not just train the model to predict *only* the next token? why predict words that are in the input, necessitating this causal mask? well, parameters are shared. When the model learns "two" by attending to "one," it's changing model parameters that help generate "five" in attending to "four." Longer sequence lengths end up being equivalent to larger batch sizes, and so this redundant-seeming way of training is actually very data efficient.